# Building a website in html5 that works on ipad, iphone and recent browsers

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, html

I am faced with the question of whether to go the route of using Html5 to build an app / website or to use iOs.

What are the pros and cons?

Would I need to use an html5 framework to build the app?

What are the limitations of using iOs?

It would be cool to use an html5 platform because iOs intuitively seems to be restrictive.

There are so many examples of what html5 can do, but they don't tend to focus on the practicality of whether that will work cross browsers. For example I was testing the native drag and drop of html5 and it doesn't work on the ipad on iOs 4.

I'm totally just starting out on this so if anyone can help me out and point me to some useful starting points, that would be fantastic.

Cheers

Andy

Comment: I would need more information about what the app is supposed to do before I could offer any type of advice.

Comment: the app is going to be a portfolio, but very content - video etc driven. The interface needs to work very well without glitches on all platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build the app using iOS, then...
* you need to know how to program in Objective C
* you can use native iOS implementation approaches for the best performance

If you want to build the app using HTML5, then...
* you need to know how to program in JavaScript and design UI in CSS
* your app will basically (see next point) work in all browsers
* you need to learn the browser variations (mostly Trident, Gecko, WebKit) to ensure proper functionality in all browsers
* you sometimes need creative workarounds to compensate for lack of direct access to native iOS features (eg menu scrolling, etc)

In my experience, apps that are graphically-intense should definitely be implemented in iOS native, while apps that aren't (eg storefronts, RSS readers, etc) can much more easily be implemented in HTML5. Your drag-and-drop example potentially falls into the former category.

As for using an HTML5 framework, that might not be a bad option. Given that you're asking this question in the first place, it sounds like you've not had a great deal of experience creating cross-browser websites, in which case you'd likely have a fairly significant learning curve in trying to create this manually from scratch. Mind you -- you'd learn an immense amount, so if you're looking to make a career out of this, then definitely avoid a framework. Frameworks inherently add some level of functional restrictions, in order to solve other challenges for you -- which is to say, they are imperfect shortcuts which can stunt your growth if you rely on them too heavily.

As for specific starting points, I don't have much to offer -- I just wanted to help clarify the lay of the land that you're surveying, and offer some context for your decision.